# Vue Transitions - how to perform a one-time on and off animation

Tags: vue.js, transition

I'm building a notes taking Vue app.
The note being edited is auto-saved every X secods.
Every time it auto saves, I want to show a small message on the bottom of the screen saying "Note Saved". This will fade in stay for 2 seconds and then fade out automatically.

I've done transitions in Vue before but not on-off transitions like this.
 I can set a property linked to the element with v-if wrapped in a transition block. But then I need to change the property twice (true-false)? Would I need to set up a timer to wait the transition to be over before setting it to false again? Seems a bit hackish. What's the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

**I think what you've described with `v-if` makes sense**... you could change the property (or data) in a `v-on:enter` method on the related component. This would nicely isolate the *behavior* to the component and be pretty apparent to future-self.

A completely different approach would be defining a single animation with keyframes that transitions from hidden to display to hidden, but that might be somewhat confusing: what is the leave transition of an element with such an enter transition? Hmm.

Comment: So, I'd do 'v-if=true' and then on v-on:enter="setFalse()" ?